# number validation with like operator in ms sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have a table with values('99','-99','99.99','-99.99','99-','$99','99#','99.99.99','-99.99.99'
,'-99-99.99');
I need output like this(99,-99,99.99,-99.99);

I tried with like operator but facing problem.

Comment: Hi @Prakash, Your question is not clear. Do you need the first 4 values? or any other logic? Please some more details.

Comment: What should `'-99.99.99'` return, and why?

Comment: Why do you want to call VB's `LIKE` operator from SQL Server?

Comment: `try_parse(col as money)`? Or as decimal. https://dbfiddle.uk/_ZvYyT0i

Comment: @ThomA OP probably means [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql), not [Like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator). Wrong tag.

Comment: One would hope, but considering that the tag obviously states "VB" ([[tag:vb-like-operator]]), my train of thought is that they *intentionally* used that tag, @RuudHelderman . The OP is yet to read the [tour], so why would they read the tags they are using though... ¯⁠\⁠_⁠(⁠ツ⁠)⁠_⁠/⁠¯

Comment: When you "face a problem", please provide details: what did you try, what were the results (including errors)?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that I understood your logic correctly but looks like you need to get only numbers. If yes, you can use isNumeric or Try_Parse for checking your string values.

```
declare @table table (strr varchar(50))

insert into @table
values
('99'),
('-99'),
('99.99'),
('-99.99'),
('99-'),
('$99'),
('99#'),
('99.99.99'),
('-99.99.99'),
('-99-99.99')

--not like '%[^0-9.-]%' is a double negative to avoid $99 because it's a number
select strr from @Table where isnumeric(strr) = 1 and strr not like '%[^0-9.-]%'

--data type depends on your expectations. I chose float
select strr from @Table where try_parse(strr as float using 'en-US') is not null
```

Both variants return the same result set:

[image]

Comment: This is the output i need. and the query is very nice. thank you somuch.